# Maven Compilation Error: (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I'm using maven in IntelliJ, JDK1.8, maven 3.2.5. Got compilation error: use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond opera. details are as follows:

```
  [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
  [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] TrainingConstructor.java:[31,55] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
  [ERROR] DTM.java:[79,21] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
  [ERROR] ticons.java:[53,44] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

Any suggestions? Is there any other configuration to set this -source level? seems it doesn't use java 1.8.

Comment: how does you maven-compiler-plugin configuration look like?

Comment: what's JAVA_HOME env varible value?

Comment: From maven plugins dropdown list, I find it using org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3

Comment: JAVA_HOME env variable is set to java jdk location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Check how your `maven-compiler-plugin` is configured, it should use java version 7 or higher:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For a more complete answer see [the one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31734791/4680812).

Comment: Thanks. I included them to POM under <build><plugins>. Some errors has gone. Still one compilation error: "Word.java:[17,22] > expected". the corresponding code is:  List<String> defaultSW =  Arrays.asList("a", "an", "and", "are"). Any idea?

Comment: this line `List<String> defaultSW = Arrays.asList("a", "an", "and", "are");` is correct, your problem is somewhere else

Comment: that's the only code I have in the java file. Any idea for this error message?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a new question and provide the sources cause the current question about maven is resolved.

Comment: @HappyCoding And it's not the only code in the file if it's on line 17, character 22...

Comment: if you use the >maven-javadoc-plugin plugin you must also configure it with the source level via <configuration>  <source>1.7</source> </configuration> . Note that the 'site' goal will also run javadoc.

Comment: @djb good point but I suppose that the original question was about the `compile` phase

Comment: yes, but I put it here in case others have the problem. I hit the error message and a search brought me here, but I had 1.7 in the compiler plugin config so the original solution did not help. Digging found the javadoc config.

Answer (score 65):

### SOLUTION 1 - Set these properties in the pom.xml

```xml
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

### SOLUTION 2 - Configure the Maven compiler plugin (always in the pom.xml)

```xml
<build>
    
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
...
```

---

### WHY IT HAPPENS

The problem arises because

> [...] at present the default source setting is 1.5 and the default target setting is 1.5, **independently of the JDK you run Maven with.** If you want to change these defaults, you should set source and target as described in Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler.
>
> [Maven Compiler Plugin Introduction (until version 3.3)](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-compiler-plugin-3.3/)

and with recent Maven versions:

> Also note that at present the default source setting is 1.6 and the default target setting is 1.6, independently of the JDK you run Maven with. **You are highly encouraged to change these defaults by setting source and target** as described in Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler.
>
> [Maven Compiler Plugin Introduction](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)

That's why changing the JDK has no effect on the source level. So you have a couple of way to tell Maven what source level to use.

### JDK VERSION TO USE?

If you set a target 1.7 like in this example be sure that the mvn command is actually launched with a jdk7 (or higher)

### LANGUAGE LEVEL ON THE IDE

Usually IDEs use maven pom.xml file as a source of project configuration.
Changing the compiler settings in the IDE not always has effect on the maven build.
That's why, the best way to keep a project always manageable with maven (and interoperable with other IDEs) is edit the pom.xml files and instruct the IDE to sync with maven.

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote and I still get that error

Answer (score 6):

You have to change your configuration:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You should learn the difference between `source/taget` option in JavaC and the usage of JDK 1.8/1.7 etc.

Apart from that you should upgrade the use maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: Thanks. also tried with version 3.2 you suggested. still an error " java:[17,22] > expected ". the corresponding code fragment is:  List<String> defaultSW = Arrays.asList("a", "an", "and", "are"). Are you aware of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If You already tried the @Sergey Pauk and @khmarbaise solution, take a look also in the settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler, there are target bytecode versions for particular modules

Comment: Doesn't affect the Maven build, though.

Comment: true, nevertheless I thought it was worth noticing, I had similar problem before, my pom.xml was set to use java 1.8 but i compiled code from intellij-idea and it took me a while to solve find the target bytecode version - it just a small hint