# I'm new in java. How to build a maven project in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, build

I just want to build a opensource program, [program]: https://qupath.github.io 
However I barely used Java and maven before, I downloaded the code of itself, but, I don't know how to build or run the code..

I already watched several utube videos, but It doesn't help. I got problem at a below point.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should start with [IntelliJ Getting Started with Maven](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/getting-started-with-maven.html)

Comment: And possibly [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258141/maven-compilation-error-use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-diamond-operator)

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll try these.

Comment: Try to use Spring Tool Suite(STS) IDE to use kind of maven project  and then search on Youtube :)

Comment: The diamond operator error is easy to fix: go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> There is a dropdown to select the project bytecode version, set this to at least Java 7.

Comment: I fixed myself as It is written following url, http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to work with a Maven project (in good shape) with recent versions of IntelliJ, you should just "File -> Open" the folder containing the pom.xml file.

After a bit of pondering, you should be able to right-click on the class you need and choose "Run" or "Debug".