# Maven Compile java error diamond operator is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i am using maven with eclipse , when Compileling the project it giving the following error

```
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/copay/CopayMobilePassBook/src/main/java/com/cherry/copay/mpassbook/process/impl/AccountsProcessImpl.java:[17,55] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] /D:/copay/CopayMobilePassBook/src/main/java/com/cherry/copay/mpassbook/process/support/ReversalProcessSupport.java:[89,88] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[INFO] 2 errors
```

But installed version of JDK is 8
project -> right click -> properties ->project facts  -> java version is 1.8

what is the problem with my maven configuration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258141/maven-compilation-error-use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-diamond-operator

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya after maven clean only this problem came .. before that it was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be maven compiler plugin configuration issues

You can check Stack over flow answer : -

[maven-compilation-error-use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-diamond-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258141/maven-compilation-error-use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-diamond-operator/31734791#31734791)

You can use proper version of JDK version

```
<properties>
    <maven-compiler-plugin>3.0</maven-compiler-plugin>
    <jdk-version>1.8</jdk-version>

</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
            <compilerVersion>${jdk-version}</compilerVersion>
            <source>${jdk-version}</source>
            <target>${jdk-version}</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```