# COMPILATION ERROR : Failed to execute maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

i tried build on jenkins simple project with maven , but i getting this error and i don't inderstand what's the issue

```
enter code here
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default- 
compile) on project server: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Whu.png]

Comment: Can you please accept one of the below answers or explain why those answers doesn't work you?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in 3 ways

1. Upgrade to JDK7 or JDK8 (meh)
2. Use maven-compiler-plugin version or later, because
3. Indicate to the maven-compiler-plugin to use source level 7 and target 7

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

or

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states `maven-compiler-plugin` should be configured with java 7 or higher version.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also update maven-compiler-plugin as 2.3.2 is really old. check this for further explanation [Maven Compilation Error: (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258141/maven-compilation-error-use-source-7-or-higher-to-enable-diamond-operator/31734791#31734791)

Comment: i don't understand where i need to change, can you explain with more details